# Image is not being set to the nest UIViewController at the UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having a problem with swift.

```
import UIKit

class StarbucksRefreshersBeverages: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {  
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
var drink = "blah"

var refreshersDrinks = ["Cool Lime Starbucks Refreshers", "Valencia Orange Starbucks Refreshers", "Verry Berry Hibiscus Starbucks Refreshers"]

var refresherDrink = "blahblah"

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return refreshersDrinks.count   
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "starbucksRefreshersPrototypeCell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = refreshersDrinks[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.refresherDrink = refreshersDrinks[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("starbucksRefreshersToImageViewSegue", sender: self) 
}
/*
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    var detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as RefreshersImageView

    detailViewController.refresherDrink = self.refresherDrink

    if self.refresherDrink == "Cool Lime Starbucks Refreshers" {

        detailViewController.refreshersImageView.image = UIImage( contentsOfFile: "coolLime.png")


    }

    if self.refresherDrink == "Valencia Orange Starbucks Refreshers" {


        detailViewController.refreshersImageView == UIImage(contentsOfFile: "valenciaOrange.png")

    }


}

*/



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if segue.identifier == "starbucksRefreshersToImageViewSegue" { // is set in interface builder


        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as RefreshersImageView

        if self.refresherDrink == "Cool Lime Starbucks Refreshers" {

            detailViewController.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "coolLime.png")

        }

        if self.refresherDrink == "Valencia Orange Starbucks Refreshers" {


            detailViewController.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "valenciaOrange.png")

        }

    }


}
}
```

In the line

```
detailViewController.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "coolLime.png")
```

I want to set the next view controller's image view to the .png file that I want to display. But when I navigate to the view controller that the image should be displayed, there is no image and I am getting no errors at all. Here is the other View Controller that the image should be displayed;

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RefreshersImageView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var refreshersImageView: UIImageView!
var refresherDrink = "blahblah"
var image: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    image = refreshersImageView.image
}
}
```

It really is frustrating and I also tried all of the stack overflow results but nın ıf them worked. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Do you definitely have a file in your project with that name?

Answer (score 1):

In `RefreshersImageView`

change:

```
image = refreshersImageView.image
```

for:

```
refreshersImageView.image = image
```

Also:

- it's bad practice to call a UIViewController `RefreshersImageView`. That gives the impression that it's just a widget, not a full-blown View Controller.
- as @Woodstock states, check that all your images are selected in your target and are copied to your App's bundle.
- check also image name capitalization

Comment: Is refreshersImageView connected to an UIImageView. Debug that just by doing: `refreshersImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "coolLime.png")` . That way you'll get always the same image, but you can be sure at least you detail VC is working

Comment: The segue `starbucksRefreshersToImageViewSegue` is set from your Master VC to detail VC or it fires touching a Cell? You should connect from VC to VC, not from Cell to VC because you're firing the segue in code

Comment: it does not show up that way either. Could there be problem with the images that I have installed? I am sure that the names are correct. That is so strange. even in the view did load, when i set it's image to coolLİme.png by default it does not show up

Comment: I couldn't really get what diego is saying, i am new to programming. :(

Comment: Then it's one of two: either your images are not added to the target you're building (look inside Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, your images should appear listed there) or if you're using an Images.xcasset, don't use the .png extension

Comment: Can you update your post with a screen capture of just these two VC's and the segue from the Storyboard?